# Where to find log files for failed push notification?

Tags: android-notifications, android-push-notification, android-log

When I try to create and send a push notificartion to my Android TV, I get following toast message on my TV:

> Developer warning for package *.
> Failed to post notification on channel "default".
> See logs for more details.

Where are those log files saved to?

Answer (score 0):

I've found it in usual logcat. But not under app package's logs, but just in **unfiltered** system ones, like:

```
2021-12-17 01:27:54.257 665-1957/? E/NotificationService: No Channel found for pkg=com.company.appname, channelId=default, id=0, tag=null, opPkg=com.company.appname, callingUid=10131, userId=0, incomingUserId=0, notificationUid=10131, notification=Notification(channel=default pri=0 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x10 color=0xffffffff vis=PRIVATE)
```